# router.route() doesnt want to work at all

Tags: express

I am trying to run router.route() with the following code

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/test').get(function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('You have reached localhost:9000/test');
    next();
});

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Running on port 9000');
});
```

But it doesn't seem like anything is happening at all. Regardless of what I do, localhost:9000/test will not return anything `Cannot GET /test`. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hook the router into your `app` with `app.use()`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('You have reached localhost:9000/test');
});

app.use(router);            // <=== add this

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Running on port 9000');
});
```

Your original code creates a router object, but that router object is not hooked up to any web server yet.  Using `app.use()`, you can hook it up to your web server so that it actually gets a chance to see the incoming requests.

Also, do not call `next()` after you call `res.send()`.  Pick one of the other.  Once you send a response, you do not want to continue routing to other routes because that will often try to then send another response, but you can only send one response to a given incoming http request.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Router().get(...)` function instead.

The `<Router>.get('/path', function() {...});` function will listen for incoming traffic to the path `/path` and then fire the `callback` function with the parameters `request`, `response` and `next`.

Example:

```js
router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('You have reached localhost:9000/test');
});
```

Full example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('You have reached localhost:9000/test');
});

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Running on port 9000');
});
```

Note: Using the `next()` function after sending a response to an incoming HTTP request will result in an error.